# How to filter moderation status with pnp js?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, 2019, pnpjs, status

I have a news portal, and I only want to show the approved news.
It is possible, with pnp js in SharePoint 2019?
I try filter with ModerationStatus, OData__ModerationStatus and _ModerationStatus name, but I cannot solve the problem.
Any idea?
Thanks!

```
let folder = await sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/folder");
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("ListTitle").currentUserHasPermissions(PermissionKind.ManageLists).then(perms => {
  this.IsCurrentUserReader = !perms;
  this._updateCallback;
});

await folder.files.expand("ListItemAllFields").orderBy("TimeCreated", false).filter('ListItemAllFields/ModerationStatus eq 0').get().then(items => {
  this.ItemCount = items.length;
  if (items.length == 0) {
    this.ErrorMessage = "There is not news";
    this._updateCallback();
  }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error or are you getting all files ignoring status filter?

Comment: I don't get any error, but no news is displayed

Comment: It is possible, that I give wrong parameter or fieldname?

Comment: Field name should be its internal name. i.e `OData__ModerationStatus`. (with two `_`).